# Command not found, make: Error 127,

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, flex-lexer

I have this make file which compiles successfully:

```
CCC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall
CCFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS = -g

common_objects = main.o tokens.o
flex_objects = flex_scanner.o 
hand_objects = hand_scanner.o 

both: flex_scanner hand_scanner

flex_scanner: $(flex_objects) $(common_objects)
    $(CCC) $(LDFLAGS) $(flex_objects) $(common_objects) -o flex_scanner

flex_scanner.o: flex_scanner.l
    flex -it flex_scanner.l > flex_scanner.cc
    $(CCC) $(CCFLAGS) flex_scanner.cc

clean:
    /bin/rm -f hand_scanner flex_scanner $(hand_objects) $(flex_objects) \
        $(common_objects) flex_scanner.cc

test: both
    flex_scanner < test1 > flex_test1.output
    hand_scanner < test1 > hand_test1.output
```

But when I try to run `make test` I get the following error:

```
flex_scanner < test1 > flex_test1.output
/bin/sh: flex scanner:command not found
make *** [test] Error 127
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Try: `./flex_scanner` ?

Comment: or you could `ln -s ~/bin/flex_scanner /path_to_exec/flex_scanner ` and `ln -s ~/bin/hand_scanner /path_to_exec/hand_scanner`

Comment: Thanks, adding "./" worked for me. Can you explain why this is so?

Comment: When you give a command like `flex_scanner`, your operating system must look for an executable by that name. It has a list of places where it looks for such things, which may or may not include "." (for the working directory). By adding "./" you are telling the OS "don't go hunting for something called 'flex_scanner', use the path I'm giving you".

Comment: If you are not in a hostile machine, you can add `export PATH=$PATH:.` to your `~/.bashrc` or similar, to search for commands in the current dir.

Answer (score 0):

([The question has been answered in the comments. Converted to a community wiki answer to suit the Q&A format of Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)).

As noted by @Brett Hale `./flex_scanner` should be used:

```
test: both
    ./flex_scanner < test1 > flex_test1.output
    hand_scanner < test1 > hand_test1.output
```

This is explained by @Beta:

> When you give a command like `flex_scanner`, your operating system must look for an executable by that name. It has a list of places where it looks for such things, which may or may not include "." (for the working directory). By adding "./" you are telling the OS "don't go hunting for something called 'flex_scanner', use the path I'm giving you".

Now, the `PATH` can me amended as explained by @JJoao:

> If you are not in a hostile machine, you can add export PATH=$PATH:. to your ~/.bashrc or similar, to search for commands in the current dir.

Or the perhaps less usefully the binaries could be added to a `PATH` dierctory by linking as explained by @Wojciech Frohmberg:

> or you could `ln -s ~/bin/flex_scanner /path_to_exec/flex_scanner` and `ln -s ~/bin/hand_scanner /path_to_exec/hand_scanner`

Most experienced unix users would avoid having a `.` on their `PATH` as it opens up the risks of running unexpected binaries.